Replacing the BJT in the current limiting circuit with a MOSFET
I was looking for a current limiting circuit and found an implementation using TL431 and a bipolar transistor.

However, I did not have a bipolar transistor at hand for the required current and voltage. But I have a powerful N channel MOSFET IRLML6344.
Can I replace the transistor without changing the circuit?
My requirements for the circuit:
The current limit is 0.5 Amperes.
Operating voltage from 20 to 22 Volts.
Link to the source of the circuit

Typeof undefined - Hi, We have been alerted that you have done a "delete and repost" of your previous question instead of editing that one to improve it. One of the differences between Stack Exchange and typical forums is SE questions should be edited to improve them - not deleted & reposted with improvements. || Since you have now received an answer here, it would cause extra work for other people if I deleted this question & undeleted the previous one, so I won't. But please note, deleting questions can damage your acct & can lead to an automatic ban, if repeated, so don't.

Okay, I understand, thanks

"powerful"?!? The IRLML6344 is a tiny 800 mW device in an SOT-23 package.

Yes this should work without issue in the present case. Note that the transistor will dissipate up to around 10 W in a short circuit case, so good heat sinking is mandatory.
The difference is that battery voltage has to be slightly higher to provide sufficient gate voltage to the MOSFET.
Battery voltage has to be at least 2.5 V + threshold voltage. The latter is 0.7 V for a BJT or Sziklai, 1.4 V for a Darlington, and for a discrete MOSFET it can be often between 2..5 V depending on the type.

Accordingly, the nominal value of the resistor R1 can be selected in such a way as to provide a minimum current through the shunt regulator? (Because the mosfet needs voltage to open.)

yes @Typeofundefined R1 has to stay similar, to provide the same regulator current of typically 1 mA.

And what about the maximum voltage of Vgs. Is there a need for a zener diode? @tobalt

The IRLML6344 is pretty much "full on" with $V_{GS}$ at 2.5 V, so as a source follower, $V_{GS}$ will never exceed that value, even when the circuit goes into current limiting - no additional protection required. Select R1 for how "hard" you want the limit to be. For example, if you make it 2 kΩ, the TL431 will be passing an additional 10 mA when the output is grounded for a total current of 0.51 A.

I have one more question, it turns out that the transistor will always minimal drop 2.5 volts + Vgs? That is, in fact, this circuit will not allow me to get the full source voltage in the case when the current is below the limit. @DaveTweed

Not exactly. At very low currents, $V_{GS}$ can be as low as a volt or so, but at higher currents (less than the limit) it will rise. And the drop across $R_{CL}$ is linear with the load current, only getting to 2.5 V when you hit the current limit. Since there's no drop across R1 until you hit the limit, the total drop across the circuit will be $V_{GS} + I × R_{CL}$. So the minimum voltage drop is about 1 V, and at the moment you hit the current limit, the voltage drop will be about 5 V.

Can I use P-CHANNEL MOSFET in order to get rid of unwanted drop on the emitter follower? I think I could introduce a few extra elements to do this. I think I could introduce a few extra elements to do this.

You can, but then you're talking about a high-side current sense amplifier and comparator to drive it. There are certainly chips like that on the market if you search using that phrase.

@Typeofundefined any way you look at this, the resistor will always drop 2.5 V * 0.5 A = 1.25 W and the transistor will always drop whatever is left of the voltage, not needed by the load to reach 0.5 A. The circuit is hilariously inefficient,  but simple and precise. Switch-Mode current sinks are much more efficient, but slightly more complicated.
